# Is there a monotonic sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that $|f^{(n)}(c_n)| \to \infty$ ($n \to \infty$)

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x) \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$, if $f(x) = 0$ on set $S \subset [a,b]$, $S$ is an infinite set, but $f(x) \not\equiv 0$ on every $[a',b'] \subset [a,b]$.

Is there exists a monotonic sequence $\{c_n\}$, such that $|f^{(n)}(c_n)| \to \infty$ ($n \to \infty$)?

Comment: Can such a $f$ even exist?

Comment: @Szeto Yes, I think $\sin{1\over x}\cdot e^{-1/x}$ on $[0,1]$ will do.